# SAS - hash in macro

Tags: sas, hashtable, sas-macro

I'm trying to turn my hash object into a macro so that I can do a match on a number of different analysis variables. Here is the part of the macro with the hash object. I feel that my issue must be with how I am calling/quoting the macros in the hash, because a different version of this hash works without the macro. Thoughts?

The errors I am getting are ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object failure.  Aborted during the COMPILATION phase. ERROR 557-185: Variable data is not an object. And then later in the object, ERROR: File DATA.TEST_BANK_ACCOUNT_ALL_REGS.DATA does not exist.

```
data data.test_&match_field._all_regs;
if _N_ = 1 then do;
    if 0 then set = data.test_&match_field._match_srt;
    declare hash contractors(dataset:"data.test_&match_field._match_srt", multidata: 'yes');
    contractors.defineKey("&match_var.");
    contractors.defineData('fpds_duns',                 
                           'xxx_dod_contractor',
                           "&match_flag.",
                           'xxx_small_contractor',
                           'xxx_medium_contractor',
                           'xxx_large_contractor',
                           'xxx_reported_relationship',
                           'xxx_joint_venture_flag');                 
    contractors.defineDone();
end;
set data.test_xxx_200;
 rc = contractors.find(key:"&match_var.");
do while (rc=0);
if xxxx_duns =  xxx_hq_parent_duns_number or
   xxxx_duns = xxx_hq_parent_duns_number or
   xxxx_duns = xxx_global_parent_duns_number then xxx_reported_relationship = 'Y';   
else xxx_reported_relationship = 'N'; 
output data.test_&match_field._all_regs;
rc = contractors.find_next(key:"&match_var.");
end;
```

`run;`

Comment: add some sample data and the values of your macro variables that reproduces the problem.  As it is, I don't think we can tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: Add the following to your code and post the log with the errors: `options mprint symbolgen;`  It may also help if you include your working code before you converted it to a macro.

Comment: You have match_field and match_var in different places. Is that intentional? You don't show how it's set or how you're calling the macro either.